# Fixing my function to transform large integers more readable with their appended Million, Billion, Thousandth string

Tags: javascript

I have this function that converts large numbers into something more readable to the human eye:
10,000,000 = 10M
10,000,000,000 = 10B

However an issue occurs when the large number is at a hundred(mill, bill, thousandth).

200,000,000,000 converts to 0.2 t (trillion) , I would like it to convert to 200B, instead of the decimal format. This is the same any number in the hundredth billion, million, thousand, etc...

```
  function convrt(val) { 
  
    // thousands, millions, billions etc.. 
    var s = ["", "k", "M", "B", "t"]; 

    // dividing the value by 3. 
    var sNum = Math.floor(("" + val).length / 3); 

    // calculating the precised value. 
    var sVal = parseFloat(( 
      sNum != 0 ? (val / Math.pow(1000, sNum)) : val).toPrecision(2)); 
    
    if (sVal % 1 != 0) { 
        sVal = sVal.toFixed(1); 
    } 

    // appending the letter to precised val. 
    return sVal + s[sNum]; 
}
```

How can I fix that with my code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to use the loop.
You can add format with decimal part of number.

```
function convrt(number) {
    postfixes = ['', 'k', 'M', 'B', 't']
    count = 0
    while (number >= 1000 && count < postfixes.length) {
        number /= 1000
        count++
    } 
    return number + postfixes[count];
}
```

**Note.** You can do this by cutting the number string (every loop you need to strip the last 3 characters of the string until the length of the string is less than 4 characters). But in this case, you will have difficulty the decimal part, if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```js
// Function
const convrt = (n) => {
  const matrix = {
    "t": 1.0e+12,
    "B": 1.0e+9,
    "M": 1.0e+6,
    "k": 1.0e+3,
    "": 1.0e+0
  };
  // Loop through matrix and return formatted value
  for(const k in matrix)
    if(Math.abs(Number(n)) >= matrix[k])
      return Math.round(Number(n) / matrix[k]) + k;
};

// Demo
console.log(convrt(215));
console.log(convrt(45145));
console.log(convrt(-6845215));
console.log(convrt(92674883122));
console.log(convrt(2192674883122));
```

Comment: It's difficult solution, especially for him. And don't let the decimal part be used. But it's good because it works with negative numbers.

Comment: Well he asked literally: "... instead of the decimal format ..." )